# Show small numbers without exponential form in PHP and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to show tiny numbers without exponential form?

```
<?php 
$a=4;
$b=799999999999999;
$c=$a/$b;
echo $c;
?>
```

I use this code in a WordPress page (PHP enabled) and it outputs 5.0E-15 instead of 0,000000000000005

I use default Twenty Sixteen theme without custom functions.

How would you edit the PHP code above in order to show the correct number?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [number_format](http://php.net/number_format) function for this.

```
<?php 
$a=4;
$b=799999999999999;
$c=$a/$b;
$d = number_format($c, 15, ',', '');
echo $d;
?>
```

Outputs: 0,000000000000005

But as you stated, you need a more dynamic solution as the decimal place isn't fixed. So here's my proposed solution.

Long version:

```
 <?php 
 $a=4;
 $b=799999999999999;
 $c=$a/$b;
 $e = 0; //this is our output variable
 if((strpos($c, 'E'))){ //does the result contain an exponent ?
    $d = explode("-",$c); //blow up the string and find what the decimal place is too
    $e = number_format($c, $d[1], ',', ''); //format with the decimal place
 }else{
    $e = $c; //Number didn't contain an exponent, return the number
 }
 echo $e;  
 ?>
```

and here's the previous code shortened down a bit:

```
<?php 
$a=4;
$b=799999999999999;
$c=$a/$b;

$d = (strpos($c,'E')) ? number_format($c,explode("-",$c)[1],',','') : $c;

echo $d;

?>
```

( I deleted my answer and reposted as I'm not sure if you got the alert that I amended my answer)